# Swap Objects in an ArrayDeque (Java)

Tags: java, swap, arraydeque

If I have an ArrayList, I can swap two objects using Collections.swap(list, indexA, indexB).

Is there anything similar for an ArrayDeque?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `ArrayDequeue` is a `Dequeue` implementation, which means it is meant to be used to insert and remove elements only at start and end of the collection. It does not provide indexed access to elements (unlike `List`).

If you need indexed access to elements, and swap operation, you should reconsider your design and use another Collection type.